# OS Directory File Search Not Showing Files Containing Name

Tags: python

I have a bunch of downloaded files that I am trying to move from my downloads to a specific folder, but for some reason when I download the files it gives a random number to the filename at the front (not consistent). So I am searching for any file with the original file name as a part of it, but it's not returning anything. Example below.

```
files = ["testing_123.pptx","othertype.doc"]
for filename in files:
    downloads = r"C:\Users\xx\Downloads"
    ls = os.listdir(downloads)
    ls2 = [s for s in ls if filename in s]
    f = ls2[0]
    original = os.path.join(downloads, f)
    target = os.path.join(dest, filename)
    shutil.move(original, target)
```

Directory shows:

```
ls = ["2467231_testing_123.pptx","4234_othertype.doc", .....]
```

Why is this not pulling anything?

Comment: Your code seems to work when I try running it, so I can't debug it — although I'm not entirely sure what you meant about "…it's not returning anything". What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It's returning a blank list... as if there were no matches

Comment: What list are you talking about? This code in not part of a function, so it `return`s nothing. What I meant was when I run the code it calls `shutil.move(original, target)` on all the matching files.

Comment: Figured it out... apparently it was searching my downloads folder too quickly so the file just wasnt there yet